# How to compute conditional expectation if two variables are known?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There are two variables $X$ and $Y$. Is it possible to compute 
$E[X|Y=x]$ if both variables have known density? Here, we do not assume two variables are independent, what I have in hand are the density function of two variables. If there exists a method, could someone provide source for that method? Any method including expansion method is fine.

Comment: Do you have the *joint* density? If so, you know the conditional density of $X$ given $Y$ and can integrate $X$ with respect to it to get the conditional expectation. If you just have the densities of the individual variables and they aren't independent, no dice.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the joint density? Expansion is also ok on the joint if the density of X and Y are known

Comment: @will_cheuk No, it is not possible to obtain the joint density.

Comment: How about solving the integral equation as follow: $\int E[X|Y=x]f_{Y}(x) dx=E[X]$? Right hand side is known, the density of Y is known, it remains to solve the Fredholm equation. But I am not sure if it is possible to solve the Fredholm equation.

Comment: You are missing the point. Knowing the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ tells you nothing about their relationship, (i.e. what $Y$ tells you about $X$) which the conditional expectation depends crucially on. The one exception would be if either $X$ or $Y$ were a constant, which would guarantee independence.

Comment: Regarding the integral equation, it should be reasonably clear that it has many solutions. For instance the constant $E(X)$ is a solution.

Comment: Are there any methods to solve it without examining its joint density? I understand that it is integral equation has many solution, should there exist a good guess for the solution?

Comment: Which of the many solutions do you want to guess? You are pretty persistent about missing the point here.

Comment: I do not need to know the joint density, just want to know if there exist a method to get the conditional expectation, even if I have expansion method on the conditional distribution. Also, for the Fredholm equation, I would like to know the usual way people can try to solve integral equation. Although there may have infinite many solution, but there should be a way to start the calculation (the final is general solution). I am just curious and want to learn deep in this field only.

Comment: You could guess $E(X)$... that would be assuming independence. You should guess the solution $$ E(X\mid Y=y)= \int x\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}dx$$ since it's the right one, but this requires you to know the joint $f_{X,Y}.$

Comment: So you mean the only method to find the solution is to compute the joint density and ther is no other method other than considering joint density?